# Can I have a custom my.ini for a website as php.ini... if as how?

Tags: php, php-ini

I want to have some changes in my.ini as.... instead of making changes in my.ini located in mysql/bin....can I make my own my.ini for my php project.. such as 
skip-external-locking

```
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_open_cache = 4096
sort_buffer_size = 2M

#InnoDB specifications
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_log_file_size = 10M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 180
```

Comment: It completely depends on whether you're the owner of the server or not, which operating system it uses and which webserver you're using. Don't simply rely on `ini_set()` as answered below, because there are cases where it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ini_set** function to change your php ini values without editing **php.ini** file.

Reffer this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: What if OP isn't the server owner and `ini_set()` is blocked? Please think your answers through before posting them..